# How to get the number/alphabet index pattern in an alphanumeric string in R?

Tags: r, arrays, regex, string, alphanumeric

Say I have a string like this:
***xyz45kpt793rsdwq1***

I need to compute its equivalent alphabet & number sequence pattern like this as output:
***3a2n3a3n5a1n***

Where,
"a" represents alphabet
"n" represents number
and the numeric value tells the count of the continuous piece of either alphabets or numbers

Here is what I tried:

```
strsplit("xyz45kpt793rsdwq1", "(?=[A-Za-z])(?<=[0-9])|(?=[0-9])(?<=[A-Za-z])", perl=TRUE)
```

I get the output as:

```
[[1]]
[1] "xyz"   "45"    "kpt"   "793"   "rsdwq" "1"
```

Then I identified whether each of the above values is a set of alphabets or numbers by doing the following (for which I get output as `FALSE` if it's a set of numbers, and `TRUE` if it's a set of alphabets):

```
x <- strsplit("xyz45kpt793rsdwq1", "(?=[A-Za-z])(?<=[0-9])|(?=[0-9])(?<=[A-Za-z])", perl=TRUE)[[1]][2]
grepl("^[A-Za-z]+$", x, perl = T)
```

I did this for each of the 6 elements. Here I've shown the code for the 2nd element addressed as `[[1]][2]` as an example.

Next, I found the length of each of the above by `nchar(x)`.
Now I can combine these to create the output **3a** for the 1st element, **2n** for the 2nd element and so on..
Eventually I can combine all of these to get the desired pattern output as **3a2n3a3n5a1n**

But this approach I've tried seems a bit of an overkill and too lengthy. And it would get too complicated to do the same if I have an entire column of strings in a dataframe - for each of which I need to compute this pattern.

Can anyone help with a line of code which can do this in a much efficient manner?

Comment: I think your existing approach isn't bad. I would generally say that trying to fit your task into a single line of code is not necessarily a good goal. This isn't code golf -- if a one-liner is too long and convoluted it is difficult for others to understand. The same functionality spread over three or four shorter lines, where each line does a single task, is often more readable.

Comment: Yes, totally agree that one single line shouldn't be my goal. What I actually need is something more efficient instead, and something which would be scalable to hundreds of string values present in a dataframe column, even though the code consists of multiple lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `gsubfn` here:

```r
library(gsubfn)
x <- "xyz45kpt793rsdwq1"
gsubfn("(\\d+)|(\\p{L}+)", function(x,y) ifelse(nzchar(x), paste0(nchar(x),"n"), paste0(nchar(y),"a")), x, perl=TRUE)
# => [1] "3a2n3a3n5a1n"
```

The PCRE regex (the `perl=TRUE` enables the PCRE regex) - `(\d+)|(\p{L}+)` - matches and captures into Group 1 (`x`) any one or more digits, or captures any one or more letters into Group 2 (`y`). If Group 1 matches (`nzchar(x)`), the replacement is the length of the match (`nchar(x)`) and `n`. Else, Group 2 matched, and the replacement is the length of the group  + `a`.

Answer (score 1):

A solution without using libraries. I don't think your approach is too lengthy, you could just take your existing logic and put it in a function and apply it to a data frame column:

```
x <- data.frame(strings = c("xyz45kpt793rsdwq1", "abs12345djf"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

my_fun <- function(strings) {
  matches <- sapply(strings, strsplit, "(?=[A-Za-z])(?<=[0-9])|(?=[0-9])(?<=[A-Za-z])", perl=TRUE)
  sapply(matches, function(x) {
    y <- ifelse(substr(x, 1, 1) %in% letters, paste0(nchar(x), "a"), paste0(nchar(x), "n"))
    paste(y, collapse = "")
  })
}

x$new_strings <- my_fun(x$strings)
x
```

Output:

```
            strings  new_strings
1 xyz45kpt793rsdwq1 3a2n3a3n5a1n
2       abs12345djf       3a5n3a
```